# Core-Data: Predicate for To-Many Relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a CoreData model with 4 entities.

Model screenshot -> http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/7857/screenshot20100209at182.png

**State**

> -StateName

**Location:**

> -locationName (attribute)
>
> -locationDescription
>
> -locationActivities (relatinship)
>
> -state (relationship)

**LocationActivities:**

> -location (relationship)
>
> -activity (relationship)

**Activities**

> -activityName(attribute)
>
> -locationsActivities (relationship)

How can i write a query that selects all Locations that have

> (activity = 'Golf' OR activity =
>   'Swimming') AND state = 'LA'

Answer (score 5):

```
// With some NSManagedObjectContext *moc
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location"
                               inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                       @"(locationActivities.activity.activityName == %@ OR 
                          locationActivities.activity.activityName == %@) AND 
                         state.stateName == %@",
                       @"Golf", @"Swimming", @"LA"]];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Basically, do a Core Data fetch as normal, then build the appropriate predicate to filter the results (as described in the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795)).

Comment: what about the LocationActivities linking table?

Comment: Fixed, but why is that entity there in the first place? You can (I believe) simply have a one-to-many relationship from Location to Activity.

Comment: this does not work. i get the error: 'to-many key not allowed here'.

I have added another entity as suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903177/coredata-many-to-many-relationships-and-nspredicate

Comment: What predicate did you use that gave you that error? With a direct to-many relationship from Location to Activity (even if the inverse is also to-many), I think that you should be able to do "ANY activities.activityName == %@" as part of your predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that in your screen shot, your `LocationActivities` entity is actually spelled `LocationAtivities` (note the missing "c").

That is enough to wreck your graph. Any predicate that looks for `LocationActivities`  will fail.

Errors like this make me hate programming. I seem to spend more time tracking down typos than I do fixing design errors.

Answer (score -1):

As an aside, you need to stop thinking in terms of tables and queries for Core Data. In Core Data those specifics of only the sqllite persistent store and you never see them or deal with them.

Entities are not tables and relationships are not linking tables. Trying to cram the object model into an SQL in your head will lead you to grief because Core Data does not work like SQL.