# What's better way to build NSPredicate with to-many deep relationships?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have three entities: EntityA, EntityB and EntityC connected with to-many relationships.

See schema for details:

[alt text http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/9974/screenshot20091220at124.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/9974/screenshot20091220at124.png)

For getting all instance of EntityA which depend from EntityB.name  I use the predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY EntityB.name like 'SomeName'"];
```

What should be predicate for getting all instance of EntityA which depend from EntityC.name?
I tried query like `@"ANY EntityB.entitiesC.name like 'SomeName'"` but get exception `"multiple to-many keys not allowed here"`.

Best regards,

Victor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My final solution is to use SUBQUERY.

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSpredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name like %@) AND (0 != SUBQUERY(entitiesB, $x, (0 != SUBQUERY($x.entitiesC, $y, $y.name like %@).@count)).@count)", nameA, nameC];
```

Unfortunately I was unable to expand this query on nsExpression objects.

Comment: Does this work with an SQLite store for both Mac OS and iOS? From the Apple documentation (from the iOS 5.0 library: Core Data Programming Guide > Persistent Store Features > Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors -- may be different for Mac OS): 

"There are additional constraints on the predicates you can use with the SQLite store:

You cannot necessarily translate “arbitrary” SQL queries into predicates."

Answer (score 2):

While I was stopped at the following decision:

First, I get all the EntityC that satisfy the condition EntityC.name equal to 'SomeName'

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@", @"SomeName];
```

...

```
NSArray *res = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Then I get an array of EntityB from above query

```
NSArray *parentBs = [res valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.parent"];
```

Than get array of EntityB that satisfy the condition EntityB.EntitiesC.name equal to 'SomeName':

```
NSExpression *leftExpression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
NSExpression *rightExpression = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:parentBs];

NSPredicate *p = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:leftExpression rightExpression: rightExpression modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:NSInPredicateOperatorType options:0];
```

I repeat the same for EntityA.

The effectiveness of this solution in doubt and I still expect a better solution for this problem.