# Filtering relationships with Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have a Core Data object graph set up such that

```
Grandparent--(hasMany)-->>Parent--(hasMany)-->>Child
```

and each entity has a `'modified'` property. I'd like to perform a fetch that returns each Grandparent entity with a modified date after a certain date. This should contain all Parent entities with the modified date after that point, and the same with the Child entity.

I can easily grab the list of Grandparents using

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"modified > %@", lastSyncDate];
```

Is there any way to write a predicate so that I can filter its relationships in the same way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just grabbing my whole object graph and filtering the relationships using

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"modified > %@", lastSyncDate];
NSArray *modifiedChildren = [[parent.children allObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

It's not terribly efficient but it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"modified > %@ OR ANY parents.modified > %@ OR ANY parents.children.modified > %@", 
                          lastSyncDate,
                          lastSyncDate,
                          lastSyncDate];
```

(Where the properties for the `Parent` and `Child` are called `parents` and `children` respectively. Just change them for whatever it is you have called them.)

I suggest you have a read of this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891

**UPDATE**

It appears you can't do that. I think you actually need to use `SUBQUERY`. This question is similar to what you want to do:
[What's better way to build NSPredicate with to-many deep relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006927/whats-better-way-to-build-nspredicate-with-to-many-deep-relationships)

Comment: This throws the exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'multiple to-many keys not allowed here'

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the ability to test it properly, but you're right that won't actually work. I've updated to mention about `SUBQUERY` and a link to another question which is similar. Hopefully that puts you on the right track.