# Core Data- NSPredicate and to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, one-to-many, relationships

I have a one to many relationship between Games and Players.  There is a relationship on Games to Players called players.

Games <-->> Players

The Games entity has a relationship called players.
Players has an attributed named 'order'

I am unable to use a predicate to query on the relationship. Here is the code I am using:

```
    -(NSArray *)returnPlayerLastAtBat: (int)rosterNo
    {
        NSError *error;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                       entityForName:@"Games" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"(finished = '%d') and (players.order = '%d')",0,rosterNo];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSArray* result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        [fetchRequest release];

return result;
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong- I am able to work with predicated throughout my project- but this one has been stuck.

Comment: I think you don't need the quotes in the predicate format. Not sure if it would break the predicate but it's worth a try.

Comment: Just FYI, table names are singular by convention (i.e Game and Player)

Comment: The quotes were for aesthetics- they don't affect the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347776/how-to-correctly-setup-a-nspredicate-for-a-to-many-relationship-when-using-core). And as the mvds mentionned, remove the quotes around the %d.

Comment: Thanks, Mattieu.  This code worked for me:  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"(finished = '%d') and (ANY players.order = '%d')",0,rosterNo];